# How to use/control errors spread operator on undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I have defined following function

```
const fn = (a) => (console.log(...a));
```

Function works perfect when I call it with parameters:

```
fn(['asd','fgh']) // prints 'asd fgh'
```

However, is there any way to call it with undefined?

```
fn() //Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable(…)
```

Only solution I can think about is to check it in the start of the function with an

```
if (a === undefined) a = '';
```

Is there any way I can make "...a" returns ' ', for example?

Comment: const fn = (a) => (console.log(a && ...a))
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...

Does not work

Comment: `const fn = (a) => (console.log(...a || ''));`

Comment: That worked perfect, thanks!

Comment: @Rayon: That spreads the empty string, which is probably rather unintuitive. Better use `...a || []`

Comment: @Bergi – Agreed... I just threw a rough thought on expected result..

Answer (score 3):

You can use default parameters. You can set up what value each parameter will have, if no value was passed in function call.

```
let fun = (a=3) => console.log(a);

fun(4); //4
fun(); //3
```

Answer (score 0):

**An alternative** is(if it has to be a oneliner):

```js
fn = a => a!==undefined && typeof a[Symbol.iterator] === 'function'? console.info(...a)  : console.info('');

fn();  // result ''
fn(1); // result ''
fn([1,2,3]); // result 1 2 3
```

If the **iterator** part isn't a problem:

```js
fn = a => a!==undefined ? console.info(...a)  : console.info('');

fn();  // result ''
 try {   
   fn(1);
}
catch(e){ 
   console.info("told you:" + e);
}; // throws an error
fn([1,2,3]); // result 1 2 3
```

Comment: Or just `fn = (a = ['']) => console.info(...a)`

Comment: Yes true i didnt want to post it since it is krizzus answer